# Can multiple users share the same Google Account, or is it against the rules?

Tags: authentication, federated-identity, google-account

Can multiple users share the same Google Account, or is it against the rules? I'm asking, because I would want to ensure that multiple people wouldn't be sharing accounts on my site that is using Federated Login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each Gmail account intended and designed for use by an individual
>   user. If you have multiple users frequently accessing the same account
>   from various locations, you may reach a Gmail threshold and your
>   account will be temporarily locked down.

Source: [Google Help](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33330)

Comment: The page doesn't include that quote anymore. And to be exact, the page is about "Google Workspaces", not Google Accounts in general. I've been looking for a statement about this for Google Accounts as well, but haven't been able to find it.